Cannot establish HTTPS connection when running as a Windows Service
I have 2 Software applications:

An interface software that normally should run as a Windows service
and an emulator whose goal is to test this Windows service

Both are

written in ASP.NET Core 3.1,
both use the Kestrel web server,
both can act as a client and as a server to each other,
both automatically choose an appropriate certificate from certificate storage (Current User or Local Machine).

To test things I generated a self signed certificate for localhost and installed it in Local Machine\Root CA.
Everything is fine when interface and emulator are running as normal applications. They can perform a bidirectional communication.
When I start the interface as Windows service, the emulator can connect to it, but when the interface software uses its client (a descendant of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<T>), it cannot connect to the emulator. The error is:
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'localhost:44357'
Please feel free to ask for additional information, because I don't know which information could be relevant.

When an application runs as a Windows service, it typically runs under a different user context (such as LocalSystem or NetworkService) than when it's running as a normal application. These accounts may not have access to the certificate stored in the Current User store. So, you can try to install the certificate in the Local Machine certificate store, under Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Personal. Then, in your application configure the Kestrel server to explicitly use a certificate from the Local Machine store.

And for the certificate in the Local Machine store, make sure the NetworkService or LocalSystem account trusts the root certificate for localhost, and give the service account proper access to the certificate's private key. Finally use the Correct Service Account to run the windows service.
